# R shiny - Warning: Error in : Only strings can be converted to symbols

Tags: r, function, shiny

I am relatively new to R shiny. I have created a function using ggplot, which works well when outside of R shiny, but throws up an "Only strings can be converted to symbols" error in Shiny. I was wondering what the problem is? i have tried changing aes to aes_string in the function, but still no luck.

I add a reproducible example

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(tidyverse)


scatter_fun<-function(data,xval,yval){
xval <- ensym(xval)
yval <- ensym(yval)

ggplot(data, aes_string(!!xval, !!yval))+
geom_point(alpha=0.25)+
theme(axis.line.x.bottom = element_line("black"),
axis.line.y.left = element_line("black"),
axis.text.x = element_blank(),
legend.title = element_blank(),
panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white",
colour = "black",
size = 0.5, linetype = "solid"),
panel.grid.major = element_line(size = 0.5, linetype = 'solid',
colour = "gray90"),
panel.grid.minor = element_line(size = 0.25, linetype = 'solid',
colour = "gray90"))+ylab(quo_name(yval))+
xlab(quo_name(xval))+
scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma)+
expand_limits(y = 0)+
geom_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE, colour="red")+
annotate("text",
hjust=-0.5,
x=0,
y=max(eval(yval, data)),
label = paste0("R=",round(cor(data[,quo_name(xval)],
data[,quo_name(yval)]),2)),
size = 6)
}

ui <- fluidPage(

titlePanel("Variable testing"),

selectInput("KPI", "Variable 1",
            names(mtcars[,2:ncol(mtcars)])),

selectInput("KPI2", "Variable 2",
            names(mtcars[,2:ncol(mtcars)])),


mainPanel(plotOutput("plot"),
verbatimTextOutput('mean'))
)



server <- function(input, output) {
  
output$plot<-renderPlot({
  scatter_fun(mtcars,input$KPI, input$KPI2)
})

output$mean <- renderText({"Hello"})



}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove all the tidy eval and use only strings with `aes_string()`:

```r
scatter_fun<-function(data,xval,yval){
  
  ggplot(data, aes_string(xval, yval))+
    geom_point(alpha=0.25)+
    theme(axis.line.x.bottom = element_line("black"),
          axis.line.y.left = element_line("black"),
          axis.text.x = element_blank(),
          legend.title = element_blank(),
          panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white",
                                          colour = "black",
                                          size = 0.5, linetype = "solid"),
          panel.grid.major = element_line(size = 0.5, linetype = 'solid',
                                          colour = "gray90"),
          panel.grid.minor = element_line(size = 0.25, linetype = 'solid',
                                          colour = "gray90"))+
    ylab(yval)+
    xlab(xval)+
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma)+
    expand_limits(y = 0)+
    geom_smooth(method="lm", se=FALSE, colour="red")+
    annotate("text",
             hjust=-0.5,
             x=0,
             y=max(data[,yval]),
             label = paste0("R=",round(cor(data[,xval],
                                           data[,yval]),2)),
             size = 6)
}
```

Comment: Please note that `aes_string` is soft-deprecated and now it's recommended to use `.data[[input$*]]` instead, see e.g. [here](https://mastering-shiny.org/action-tidy.html#example-ggplot2)